# Access Pods project directory in post install hook

Tags: cocoapods, post-install

In my podfile I am using a post install hook in my podfile to add build phase scripts to the Pods project targets and build each of the targets. The problem I am having is I that am using

`system "xcodebuild -target #{target.name} -sdk iphonesimulator"`

which is building the current Pods project as I am in the Pods directory. So what I need is to change to the directory of the Pods project being generated (I assume it is stored in a temp directory and then copied to the final Pods directory after the post install hook). So is there a way to access the directory of the project which I am referencing below so that I can run xcodebuild in that directory?

```
post_install do | installer |
  installer.project <-- need the directory of this file
end
```

Thanks,
Liam.

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying to replicate this plugin: [cocoapods-native-integration](https://github.com/neonichu/cocoapods-native-integration). But otherwise, you *should* be able to access the xcodeproj path via `target.user_project_path` seen [here](https://github.com/neonichu/cocoapods-native-integration/blob/master/lib/cocoapods_plugin.rb)

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking into it. So I tried the target.user_project_path but that gives me an undefined method crash. Maybe I am barking up the wrong tree using xcodebuild but as of yet i can't find any way to build a target of the project passed in with the installer in the post install hook. I'm guessing that at that point that the Pods project passed into the installer is just stored in a variable for now which is why I cant find it's directory as it probably doesn't exist yet.

Comment: But if I am able to add build phases to the target it seems like I should have some way to then build that target.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the API for the installer object, http://www.rubydoc.info/github/cocoapods/cocoapods/Pod/Installer